# Python - breaking while loop with function (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I have a project that involves a raspberry pi, the dothat 16x2 lcd display and some python code. I am essentially trying to make a dynamic while loop that displays information on the lcd. I am also trying to add a function that cancels the while loop by pressing one of the touch buttons (reference: https://github.com/pimoroni/dot3k/blob/master/python/REFERENCE.md)

This is what I got so far:

```
import dothat.lcd as l
import dothat.backlight as b
import dothat.touch as t
from time import sleep
import signal
import os

def main():
     i=0
     k=0
     while True:
          l.clear()                   # Clear LCD screen
          b.hue(1.5)                  # Set background color
          l.set_cursor_position(0, 1) # Set cursor position on LCD
          l.write("%s" % k)           # Write variable "k" to LCD
          @t.on(t.CANCEL)             # When CANCEL button is pressed then go to function
          def cancel(ch, evt):        
               i=1                    # Set variable "i" as 1
               return
          if i == 1:                  
               break
          k=k+1
          sleep(1)
     l.clear()                         # Clear LCD screen
     b.off()                           # Turn the LCD Backlight off
     cmd='pkill python'                # 
     os(cmd)                           # Kill all python processes
     signal.pause()                    
main()
```

The while loop is running but it won't break when the button is pressed. Ideas?

Comment: Can you give more details on the problem? Is it not running/throwing an error, or it's just not stopping ?

Comment: The while loop is running, but it wont break when the button is pressed

Comment: I'm not familiar with that annotation, are you sure that the `cancel` method is actually used? Have you tried adding a `print` there?  Also, I think that _if_ it were used it would create a new local `i` instead of changing the `i` existing in the enclosing scope.

Comment: Your example code is apparently missing an import: `import dothat.touch as t`. Even though it's not the cause of the problem, others may be confused when reading it. I would suggest adding this import to improve your question.

Comment: You need to add a 'global i' statement to main and cancel function definitions. Btw i is a cr*p name for the variable, it should be called something like cancelled and you should assign true and false not 0 and 1. And yes i was confused by the missing import.

Comment: @barney Yeah, this was just a quick draft of a concept script for a similar project I was working on, so I was a bit lazy on the variable names and boolean expressions. I added the global statements in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38175123/6544053

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, though I'm getting errors about the 'module' object not being callable regarding os(cmd).

The code:

```
def main():
     global i
     i=0
     k=0
     while True:
          l.clear()
          b.hue(1.5)
          l.set_cursor_position(0, 1)
          l.write("%s" % k)
          @t.on(t.CANCEL)
          def cancel(ch, evt):
               global i
               i=1
               return
          if i == 1:
               break
          k=k+1
          sleep(1)
     l.clear()
     b.off()
     cmd='pkill python'
     os(cmd)
     signal.pause()
main()
```

Comment: the error message btw:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 29, in main
    os(cmd)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable`

Comment: `os` is a module, what you want is probably the `subprocess.call` function. But you also could exit your code with `exit(0)`, or just let it end naturally.

Answer (score -1):

I don't have a dothat LCD display, so I can't test your code. But I think @Pigface333 was right, the `i` inside `cancel` is a local variable, thus the `i` in your `if` statement is not set to 1 after pressing Cancel. The following code demonstrates that:

```
from time import sleep

def main():
    i = 0
    k = 0
    while True:
        def cancel():
            print "inside cancel"
            i = 1
            return
        cancel()
        if i == 1:
            break
        k = k+1
        sleep(1)
    exit(0)
main()
```

This will print `inside cancel` every 1 second, but won't exit, showing that the `i` inside `cancel` is a local variable. To fix it, you can create a class that stores the cancellation status:

```
from time import sleep

class Cancel(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.is_cancelled = False

    def cancel(self):
        self.is_cancelled = True


def main():
    canceller = Cancel()
    while True:
        canceller.cancel()
        if canceller.is_cancelled:
            break
        sleep(1)
    exit(0)
main()
```

The same method can be applied to your code:

```
import dothat.lcd as l
import dothat.touch as t
import dothat.backlight as b
from time import sleep
import signal


class Cancel(object):

    def __init__(self,):
        self.is_cancelled = False

    @t.on(t.CANCEL)
    def cancel(self, ch, evt):
        self.is_cancelled = True
        return


def main():
    k = 0
    cancel = Cancel()
    while True:
        l.clear()                    # Clear LCD screen
        b.hue(1.5)                   # Set background color
        l.set_cursor_position(0, 1)  # Set cursor position on LCD
        l.write("%s" % k)            # Write variable "k" to LCD
        if cancel.is_cancelled:
            break
        k = k+1
        sleep(1)
    l.clear()                         # Clear LCD screen
    b.off()                           # Turn the LCD Backlight off
    signal.pause()
    exit(0)
main()
```

To help understanding why the original code didn't work and why using a class is a good idea, I suggest reading about Python's [variable's scope](http://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) and [Object-Oriented Prograaming in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html).

Comment: This is a very complicated way of adding access to a global variable